# Labeling a circuit element with its symbol and value on both sides

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have modified the circuit code given in [Voltage sign convention (European vs. American) in Circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/voltage-sign-convention-european-vs-american-in-circuitikz) to serve my presentation in circuit making. However, ***I am unable to change the voltage source into american style*** [-ve polarity assigns to the terminal connecting to ground]. I looked through the manuals of both circuitikz and tikz but could not get an answer. My question is to **how I can label circuit element(s) with its value and the symbol [american format] on both sides in tikzpicture environment**. Please help me.

Here is the modified code for your reference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages,american currents]{circuitikz}
%\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,circuits.ee.IEC,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,american,x=2cm,y=2cm, semithick, every info/.style={font=\footnotesize}, small circuit symbols, set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
\draw (0,0) to [ground={near start, rotate=180}] (0,1)
          to [voltage source={near start, info=$V_S$,info'=$5\mbox{V}$}] (0,3)
          to [break contact={info=$t_0$}] (2,3)
          to [inductor={info=$L$,info'=$1\mbox{H}$}] (3,3)
          to [resistor={info=$R$, info'=$47\Omega$}] (6,3)
          to [capacitor={info'=$C$, info=$247\mbox{pF}$}] (6,1)
          to [ground={near end}] (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wanted to replace the european symbol into american symbol]

Here is another style with little bit of clean codes, however, both the component symbol and its value are on the same side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, circuits.ee.IEC, positioning}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,american,x=2cm,y=2cm, semithick, every info/.style={font=\footnotesize}, small circuit symbols, set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
     \draw (0,0) node[shape=ground]{}
    to [V, l=\mbox{$V_S=\SI{5}{\volt}$}] (0,1)
    to [cspst , l =$t_0$] (1,1)
    to [L, l=\mbox{$L=\SI{1}{\henry}$}] (2,1)
    to [R, l=\mbox{$R=\SI{47}{\ohm}$}] (3,1)
    to [C, l=\mbox{$C=\SI{247}{\pico\farad}$}] (3,0)
    to (3,0) node[shape=ground]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and output of the above code:

[image]

The last example uses tikz with circuittikz library. *But labeling on both sides of the component in american format is still unsuccessful*!

Comment: As far as I know, with `circuitikz` one can not directly place labels on both sides of and element, say a voltage source. Indeed the documentation shows two ways `l^` and `l_` to differentiate the cases. If you really want to do so, you should specify manually one label, once have chosen `l_` or `l^`.

Comment: One idea would be to do it by force! Something like that could be useful...`\draw[red] (-2.7,1.5) node[above right] {\footnotesize $+V_0$};`Give the correct cordinates and I beleive that you will be OK!

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino, thanks for the information. You know we can use either l^ or l_ but not both. I wanted to use both in american formats. It's possible in european formats as shown in first example above.

Comment: @Thanos, thanks a lot for another tips using force method. I did that using another force method as shown in last example above. I was just looking for a normal way if possible. It may help me in reducing code size.

Comment: @Khaaba, I am not sure I am aware of one more compact way of solving that. Sorry;)

Comment: @Thanos, Please share.

Comment: My mistake...I forgot an `if`, so I am rephrasing...I am not sure if I am aware of one more compact way of solving that...

Comment: I'm not aware if you can do it with `circuitikz`; I guess no because one could specify one label at a time. Without hacking the package, you can't..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Old question, but in the time since it was asked an improvement has been made to `CircuiTikz` to allow this behavior.

> Since Version 0.7, beside the original label (l) option, there is a new option to place a second label, called annotation (a) at each bipole. Up to now this is a beta-test and there can be problems. For example, up to now this option is not compatible with the concurrent use of voltage labels.
>
> The position of (a) and (l) labels can be adjusted with `_` and `^`, respectively.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, circuits.ee.IEC, positioning}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,american,x=2cm,y=2cm, semithick, every info/.style={font=\footnotesize}, small circuit symbols, set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
        \draw (0,0) node[shape=ground]{}
    to [V, invert, l=\mbox{$V_S$}, a={\SI{5}{\volt}}] (0,1)
    to [cspst , l =$t_0$] (1,1)
    to [L, l=\mbox{$L$}, a=\SI{1}{\henry}] (2,1)
    to [R, l=\mbox{$R$}, a=\SI{47}{\ohm}] (3,1)
    to [C, l_=\mbox{$C$}, a^=\SI{247}{\pico\farad}] (3,0)
    to (3,0) node[shape=ground]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the manual you should correctly name your voltage source with `american voltage source`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages,american currents]{circuitikz}
%\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,circuits.ee.IEC,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,american,x=2cm,y=2cm, semithick, every info/.style={font=\footnotesize}, small circuit symbols, set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
\draw (0,0) to [ground={near start, rotate=180}] (0,1)
          to [american voltage source={near start, info=$V_S$,info'=$5\mbox{V}$}] (0,3)
          to [break contact={info=$t_0$}] (2,3)
          to [inductor={info=$L$,info'=$1\mbox{H}$}] (3,3)
          to [resistor={info=$R$, info'=$47\Omega$}] (6,3)
          to [capacitor={info'=$C$, info=$247\mbox{pF}$}] (6,1)
          to [ground={near end}] (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @s_C, Have you tried running the modified code? It's giving me this error **! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circuitikz/info' and I am
 going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.** when I changed the voltage source to american voltage source in the code!

Comment: I think it's more your part that follows the name of the component.
Normally you should use `label`. For example :
`to [american voltage source,l=\SI{5}{\V}] (0,3)`
assuming that you use the second line with `\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}`.

Comment: Agreed. But still I am unable to label both sides of the component/element with fewer codes.

Answer (score 2):

A force method with `path` command is given below[reference:http://pdp7.org/blog/?p=133, however, this increases number of lines in the code.

***Force method MWE:***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, circuits.ee.IEC, positioning}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,american,x=2cm,y=2cm, semithick, every info/.style={font=\footnotesize}, small circuit symbols, set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
\draw (0,0) node[shape=ground]{}
    to [V, l=$V_S$] (0,1)
    to [cspst , l =$t_0$] (1,1)
    to [L, l=$L$] (2,1)
    to [R, l=$R$] (3,1)
    to [C, l_=$C$] (3,0)
    to (3,0) node[shape=ground]{};
\path (0.2,0) to node [right] {$\SI{5}{\volt}$} (0.2,1);
\path (1,0.9) to node [below] {$\SI{1}{\henry}$} (2,0.9);
\path (2,0.9) to node [below] {$\SI{47}{\ohm}$} (3,0.9);
\path (3.2,1) to node [right] {$\SI{247}{\pico\farad}$} (3.2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Its output after running:

[image]